# Prevent "url action/load" from React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, redux, react-router

I'm new with react router and I tried to do one simple thing, I hope. Indeed I want to prevent my browser to try to load an url, I hope I'll be clear.

In fact I have a NavBar with multiples buttons on it and when I click on one of them, the URL changed but nothing happend, the render is exactly the same.
[image: Before click] [image: After click]

But when I pressed **Enter** or right click and **'Open Link in a new Tab'** an error message is visible **[image: (Cannot GET /140009647639368)]**

It's what I want to fix to obtain the same result as previous.

I put you next sample of code to help you. I hope I was clear and thanks in advance for you help.

```
    *`navbarComponent.js`*


        render(){
            return (
                <Navbar inverse fluid>
                  <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                      Beam Viewer
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                  </Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Collapse>
                  <Nav>
                    {this.props.BpmList.map((bpm, index) => (
                      <LinkContainer key={index} to={'/'+bpm.key}><NavItem>{bpm.name}</NavItem></LinkContainer>
                    ))}
                  </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
              </Navbar>
           );

          }

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

   *index.js*

        class Main extends React.Component{

        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){

          console.log(nextProps);

        }

          render(){
            return (
              <div>
                <NavBar />
                <Options />
                <Infos />
                <Video />
              </div>
            )
          }
        }



    ReactDom.render(<Provider store={store}>
                    <Router history={browserHistory}>
                      <Route path='/' component={Main}/>
                      <Route path='/:bpmKey' component={Main}/>
                    </Router>
                    </Provider>,
                    document.getElementById('main'));
```

Comment: Your problem is most like on Web server side, not on router. What server do you use? You must provide redirect to index.html instead of allowing it to fail searching for not existing document

Comment: I used bottle server

Comment: As far as I know it supports redirects. However if using hashes in url is acceptable for you redirects does not worth it

Comment: Ok, thanks for infos and thanks for your help too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do that, the browser tries to get this route from your server. Since your server doesn't have it, it shows that error. One way to make it work, is to use `hashHistory` instead of `browserHistory`.

Comment: That's work ! Thanks a lot :) What is the differences beetween hash and browser ?

Comment: Yep I must wait 3 minutes since you posted it :)

Comment: The difference is that `browserHistory` uses the browser's `history` api.